# How could I pass a dynamic set of arguments to Go's command exec.Command?

Tags: go, command, exec

I came across a question on here relating to arguments being passed to Go's `exec.Command` function, and I was wondering if there was a way do pass these arguments dynamically? Here's some sample code from sed question:

```
package main

import "os/exec"

func main() {
    app := "echo"
    //app := "buah"

    arg0 := "-e"
    arg1 := "Hello world"
    arg2 := "\n\tfrom"
    arg3 := "golang"

    cmd := exec.Command(app, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3)
    out, err := cmd.Output()

    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    print(string(out))
}
```

So as you can see each arg is defined above as `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`. They are passed into the `Command` function along with the actual command to run, in this case, the `app` var.

What if I had an array of arguments that always perhaps had an indeterministic count that I wanted to pass through. Is this possible?

Comment: You should know that passing parameter to `os` command might not be a good idea
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Like this:

```
args := []string{"what", "ever", "you", "like"}
cmd := exec.Command(app, args...)
```

Have a look at the language and tutorial on golang.org.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the [flag library](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/), which has worked for me. This is a different example but it uses the concept of accepting dynamic arguments.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)
func main() {
        flag.Parse()    
        arg1, arg2 := strings.Join(flag.Args()[:1], " "), strings.Join(flag.Args()[1:], " ")
        cmd := exec.Command(arg1, arg2)
        err := cmd.Start()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Printf("Waiting for command to finish...")
        log.Printf("Process id is %v", cmd.Process.Pid)
        err = cmd.Wait()
        log.Printf("Command finished with error, now restarting: %v", err)
}
```

And running like this

```
$ go run main.go node ../web-test/index.js
2019/01/26 13:32:29 Waiting for command to finish...
2019/01/26 13:32:29 Process id is 3582
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest method is just like [Volker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22781927/9935654), using Variadic (`...`) to assist.

```golang
exec.Command("./myProgram.exe", []string{"foo", "bar"}...)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the `Stdin`, writing all the data you want to pass in into buffer.

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("")
var buf bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdin = &buf
bur.Write()
```

You might consider using a JSON string for the input. Another program can then read this stdin data to get the content you want to pass.

```golang
bs, err := json.Marshal(config)
buf.Write(bs)
```

#### Full Example

`a.go`

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

type Config struct {
    User string
    Para []any
}

func main() {
    // cmd := exec.Command("./myProgram.exe", []string{"foo", "bar"}...) // call from exe
    cmd := exec.Command("go", []string{"run", "program/b.go", "foo", "bar"}...)
    // cmd := exec.Command("python", []string{"b.py", "foo", "bar"}...) // call from python
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdin = &buf

    config := Config{
        "Carson",
        []any{
            "hello world",
            123,
        },
    }
    bs, err := json.Marshal(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    buf.Write(bs)

    out, err := cmd.Output() // run and wait for it finished
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("output:\n%s\n", out)
}
```

`b.go` or (myProgram.exe)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type Config struct {
    User string
    Para []any
}

func main() {
    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "MyProgram Args:%v\n", os.Args[1:])
    // fmt.Printf("MyProgram Args:%v\n", os.Args[1:]) // same as above, I just want to emphasize the object it writes to.

    bs, err := io.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var config Config
    if err = json.Unmarshal(bs, &config); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "MyProgram Get:\n%+v", config)
}
```

b.py

```
import sys
import json

sys.stdout.buffer.write(str.encode(f"MyProgram Args:{sys.argv[1:]}"))
config_raw: bytes = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
config = json.loads(config_raw)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(str.encode("MyProgram Get:" + json.dumps(config)))
```

a.go output

```
output:
MyProgram Args:[foo bar]
MyProgram Get:
{User:Carson Para:[hello world 123]}
```